# Resize QWidget to hold just the current widgets, when the set of widgets change

Tags: qt, qwidget, qlayout

Let's say there is a `QWidget` whose layout is vertical. This layout has a button (bt1) and another layout (`hLayout`).

The app works so that clicking in bt1 add/remove a button from `hLayout`.

The first time the button is added the window gets bigger (width increase) to hold the new button. Next click hides the button. But hiding the button does not make the window shrink. I would like to have the same size as before the button was added.

Whats the approach to properly shrink the window when the button is removed? Or more generally, what's the approach to make the window get just enough size?

Answer (score 0):

Just call `widget->resize(widget->minimumSize())` after removing the button from `hLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

As long as doing explicit size adjustments with resize implies to cover all possible events there is lighter and smarter approach to make the widget resize properly automatically. Have a look at [QWidget::setSizePolicy](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setSizePolicy-1) and [QSizePolicy](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html).

In situation like yours I often use:

```
// your specific code and size policy *may* differ
widget->setMinimumSize(width, height);
widget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
```

and don't interfere with event handlers to resize to specific size in such or many cases.